# How to add data into two dependent table in django

Tags: python, django

Here's my files(below), I don't know how to add disease and symptoms into database (1-M relationship)

webpage looks like:

dname:|____________|

type: |____________|

symptom:|___________| |add|

|finish|

---

1. Add dname,type of disease
2. Add 1st symptom of that disease and click add button
3. Add 2nd symptom of that same disease and click add button
4. Do for all symptoms
5. click finish to complete insertion of 1st disease

I am not able to manage this scenario. Since I have to add multiple symptoms how can I access Disease id because at this moment disease entry is not present in the database.

**models.py**

```
class Disease(models.Model):
    did = models.AutoField(verbose_name='Disease Id', primary_key=True)
    dName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    dtype = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Symptoms(models.Model):
    sid = models.AutoField(verbose_name='Symptoms Id',primary_key=True)
    sname = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease,related_name='symptoms',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```
class DiseaseForm(ModelForm):
    dname = forms.CharField()
    type = forms.ChoiceField()

    class Meta:
        model = Disease
        fields = "__all__"

class SymptomForm(ModelForm):
    sname = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Symptoms
        fields = "__all__"
```

**Views.py**

```
class AddDisease(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'personal/disease.html'

    def get(self, request):
        dform = DiseaseForm()
        sform = SymptomForm()
        ddata = Disease.objects.all()
        sdata = Symptoms.objects.all()
        args = {'dform': dform,'sform': sform,'ddata':ddata,'sdata':sdata}

        return render(request,self.template_name,args)
```

**disease.html**

```
<body>
   <form method="post">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ dform.as_p }}
       {{ sform.as_p }}
       <input type="button" class="btn" name="addbtn" value="click">
   </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Disease` is referred as the foreign key, as you said, you cannot add any `Symptom` before you know the actual `id` of `Disease`. The relationship between `Disease` and `Symptom` is `1:m` as you defined. Though I think the ideal relationship between them is `m:n`, because a `Disease` could have many `Symptom`s and a `Symptom` could belong to many `Disease`s, at this scenario, you need a middle table that stored associated record, e.g., `(disease_id, symptom_id)`, see [Many-to-Many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many)

Anyway, in your scenario, the steps you could do are:

1. First get or create a `Disease` instance. You can define a function, e.g., `get_or_create_disease`, this function should first query the database to check whether the `dname` exists in the database, if not, insert a new instance and return the new inserted else return the existing one.
2. Now you have the instance of `Disease` which owns the `id`, you can insert all `Symptom`s.

Here is a pseudo code:

```
def get_or_create_disease(db, dname):
    di = db.session.query(Disease).filter(dname=dname).one_or_none()
    if di is not None:
        return di
    else:
        di = Disease(dname=dname)
        db.session.add(di)
        try:
            db.session.commit()
            return di
        except SQLAlchemyError as e:
            db.session.rollback()
            ...

def handle_data(db, form):
    di = get_or_create_desease(db,form['dname'])
    for sp in form['symptoms']:
        di.symptoms.append(Symptom(sp))
    try:
        db.session.commit()
    exception SQLAlchemyError as e:
        db.session.rollback()
        ...
```

The pseudo shows only the logical. I only have experience of `SQLAlchemy`.

Hope this would be helpful.